# Parsing JSON String in Android Studio

Tags: json, kotlin, parsing

Im trying to convert a String to a JSON Object, but im getting following Error Message

```
E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value {"data":[{"temperaturaussen":12,"feuchtaussen":77.41,"temperaturbadezimmer":21}]} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Im getting my Data like this

```
val url = URL("url")
val connection : URLConnection = url.openConnection()
connection.connect()
val bufferedInputStream = BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream())
val bufferedReader : BufferedReader = bufferedInputStream.bufferedReader(Charsets.UTF_8)
val stringBuffer = StringBuffer()
for (line in bufferedReader.readLines()){
    stringBuffer.append(line)
}
bufferedReader.close()
val fullJson : String = stringBuffer.toString()
```

I know the Json String from the url is valid, as i checked it on https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/, which looks like this

```
"{\"data\":[{\"temperaturaussen\":12,\"feuchtaussen\":77.41}]}"
```

but why am i getting this Error Message when i try to convert it into a JSON?

```
try {
        val dataJson = JSONObject(fullJson)
    } catch (e: JSONException) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data $e")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the JSON you are trying to parse is not a JSON object (i.e. `{...}`) but merely a JSON string (i.e. `"..."`), because the quotes seem escaped (i.e. `\"` instead of `"`).

For instance this is a **valid JSON string**, but it is **not a valid JSON object**:

```json
"{\"data\":[{\"temperaturaussen\":12,\"feuchtaussen\":77.41}]}"
```

while this is a valid JSON object:

```json
{"data":[{"temperaturaussen":12,"feuchtaussen":77.41}]}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the below code

```
try {
    val dataJson = new JSONObject(fullJson)
} catch (e: JSONException) {
    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data $e")
}
```